# How do you move sentences in orgmode?

Tags: org-mode, sentences

In orgmode you can move subtrees up and down using `org-metaup` and `org-metadown`. I use it all the time to move paragraphs around.

Is it possible to do the same with sentences inside a paragraph?

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget the vanilla sentence commands. The main ones out of the box that might be relevant here are `transpose-sentences`, `mark-end-of-sentence`, `kill-sentence` (**`M-k`**), and `backward-kill-sentence` (**`C-x <backspace>`**).

Others include: `backward-sentence` (**`M-a`**), `forward-sentence` (**`M-e`**, `repunctuate-sentences`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use drag-stuff: https://github.com/rejeep/drag-stuff.el

```el
(require 'drag-stuff)
(drag-stuff-global-mode t)
(add-to-list 'drag-stuff-except-modes 'org-mode) # concurent
(eval-after-load "org"
    '(progn
       (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-s-<up>") 'drag-stuff-up)
       (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-s-<down>") 'drag-stuff-down)))
```

Comment: drag-stuff doesn't seem to have a function to move sentences among other sentences within a paragraph, but it looks like a cool package; thanks for sharing it.